# Ideal way to create first admin role for a marketplace store

Tags: e-commerce, admin, marketplace

I am building a small electronics marketplace from scratch where users can buy or sell their electronics online. The marketplace will have three types of users -

1. Regular users with ability to buy a product and add a product listing to sell
2. Moderators to remove spam and edit existing listings
3. Admins - with moderator rights plus ability to add, promote and delete moderators, and add new admins.

I am not sure what would be the ideal way to create the first admin account. One way it to just add/modify the admin account in my database myself (by the developer). Is it the only way? Am I sweating too much on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an admin account using your interface, because you would have no way of proving that you have the authority to create such an account.

Instead, you should create an admin account either directly through your database system, or create a standard user account and give it administrator permissions.

If your system is designed well, there should be no way for you to give yourself admin permissions without direct access to your system. If it is possible, anyone could create an administrator account for themselves.